# Aligning scores between the Child Behaviour Checklist (CBCL) and The Brief Infant-Toddler Social and Emotional Assessment (BITSEA)

Tags: psychometrics, growth-mixture-model

I am currently conducting a longitudinal secondary data analysis. Due to the nature of the data that has previously been collected and my proposed analysis (Growth Mixture Modelling), I am needing to appropriately align scores from the Child Behaviour Checklist with the Brief Infant-Toddler Social and Emotional Assessment. Currently, I have been recommended methods which produce a single binary variable however I am wanting to standardise the scores between these measures to yield continuous variables instead of categorical (and look to safeguard the variance in the data). I am wondering whether any researcher has had experience in aligning scores from these specific measures in their own research or are aware of studies which have done this? If so, I will be interested to view/learn and/or even discuss such methods. Thank you in advance.